# Solaris JMS Client connect to Weblogic 11g t3s security problem

Tags: java, security, jms, weblogic, weblogic11g

When I try to connect Weblogic t3s protocol in Solaris Server, it shows this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not enough cryptography available to enable a cipher suite!
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSSystem.resetCipherSuiteSupport(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSSystem.setCertificateSupport(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSSystem.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSSystem.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.net.ssl.SSLContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.bea.sslplus.CerticomSSLContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at weblogic.security.utils.SSLSetup.getSSLDelegateInstance(SSLSetup.java:122)
        at weblogic.security.utils.SSLContextWrapper.<init>(SSLContextWrapper.java:48)
        at weblogic.security.utils.SSLContextWrapper.getInstance(SSLContextWrapper.java:43)
        at weblogic.security.utils.SSLSetup.getSSLContext(SSLSetup.java:238)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.SSLClientInfo.getSSLSocketFactory(SSLClientInfo.java:101)
        at weblogic.socket.ChannelSSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(ChannelSSLSocketFactory.java:170)
        at weblogic.socket.ChannelSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(ChannelSSLSocketFactory.java:77)
        at weblogic.socket.ChannelSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(ChannelSSLSocketFactory.java:114)
        at weblogic.socket.BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.createSocket(BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.java:133)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.newSocketWithRetry(MuxableSocketT3.java:206)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.connect(MuxableSocketT3.java:375)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.ConnectionFactoryT3S.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryT3S.java:34)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1773)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.findOrCreateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1416)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:437)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:315)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:251)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:194)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:238)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:200)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:170)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:153)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate$1.run(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:344)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:147)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:339)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
```

I have define the following parameters:

```
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=weblogic.net -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=CustomTrust -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreType=JKS -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName=keystore -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhrase=passphrase -Dssl.debug=true -Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true
```

How can I fix it? Same source and same parameters is working in Windows.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution comes a bit late in the day, but is meant for others having the same problem.

Apparently, the accepted solution of adding webserviceclient+ssl.jar to the classpath works, since the WebLogic Full Client - wlfullclient.jar has references to other JARs in its MANIFEST.MF file. Adding the webservices client JAR resolves the issue, since it appears to have the minimum set of classes required for correct operation of the client when using SSL/TLS. The error is usually encountered when copies of the wlfullclient.jar and wlcipher.jar are made in a different directory, and added to the classpath. The JVM then fails to load other dependent classes from JARs that are referenced from within the MANIFEST file.

The actual solution would be to add the wlfullclient.jar that is generated in the *WL_HOME*\server\lib directory, to the CLASSPATH. All other dependent JARs would then be picked up via the appropriate classloader, since the manifest references these via relative directory paths.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same JVM vendor on both machines?

Most likely the CA used to generate the keystore is available on the Windows truststore but not available on Solaris, **the assumption being the keystore was generated in Windows and the CA is not yet shipped with the JRE being used on Solaris**. The differences are discussed [here](http://mynotes.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/difference-between-keystore-truststore/).

How to [configure](http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.3/security/i379776.html) the truststore to add a CA

Comment: I have build a new trust store and store Weblogic CA. Also I have use absolute path pointed to the file. THX

Answer (score 1):

Finally, We got the solution.

Just add webserviceclient+ssl.jar to your classpath will solve the problem.

- webserviceclient+ssl.jar not included in wlfullclient.jar.

Comment: Yeah, a JMS client needs a jar for webservices, this is so obvious. And why the hell is this jar in the classpath under windows!? Madness!

Comment: I have no idea. I double check my windows environment, there are 2 environment variables:

WEBLOGIC_HOME=D:\weblogic\bea10.3\wlserver_10.3
WL_HOME=D:\weblogic\bea10.3\wlserver_10.3

But I don't think this is related.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you `keystore` file is picked up? Maybe try to use an absolute path when specifying the `-Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName` option.

Also, are the classpath of the JMS client really identical in both environments?

Try to provide `wlserver_10.3/server/lib/wlfullclient.jar` (that you create by running the command `java -jar wljarbuilder.jar`) **and** `wlserver_10.3/server/lib/wlcipher.jar` (yeah, `wlfullclient.jar` is not that full!) on the classpath.

Comment: ya, The wlcipher.jar is in the classpath and Key store is absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

This has been simplified for 10.3.4 and above Weblogic.

Just add the wlthint3client.jar from the /server/lib directory to your client's Classpath

I've only confirmed this works for ejb communication but the docs state

> This release supports the following:

```
Oracle WebLogic's T3/T3S protocol for Remote Method Invocation (RMI), including RMI over HTTP (HTTP tunneling). For more information on WebLogic T3 communication, see "Using WebLogic RMI with T3 Protocol" in Programming RMI for Oracle WebLogic Server.

Access to JMS, JMX, JNDI, and EJB resources available in WebLogic Server.
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13717/wlthint3client.htm